# How can XSLT split an element into two?

Tags: xslt, split, element

I'm a novice at XSLT. My XML looks like this:

```
<bases>    
    <marker>
       <name>Naha Air Base</name>
       <active>1955-1971</active>
    </marker>
</bases>
```

and I want to transform it into this:

```
<bases>
    <marker>
       <name>Naha Air Base</name>
       <begin>1955</begin>
       <end>1971</end>
    </marker>
</bases>
```

What's the XSLT, please?

Comment: Use the `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with based on the suggestion. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="active">
    <begin>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(text(),'-')"/>
    </begin>
    <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
    <end>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(text(),'-')"/>
    </end>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```